# Making function of class outside the body of class

Tags: c++

If we have to declare proto type inside of public tag for class then what is the benefit of making functions outside of class

Comment: To separate declaration and definition (e.g.: into header and implementation file)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, there are mainly 2 reasons:

- a matter of style:

  Some of us prefere keeping individual blocks of code small. Putting the method definitions outside of the class definition helps in keeping the class definition small. You may or not agree on that.
- separate compilation:

  A common usage is to put the class definition in an include file to allow other compilation units to use it. As it will be included in several files, it will be compiled several times. So it can make sense on a performance build point of view to keep that include file small.

  In addition, usages recommend to keep individual files in a projet small. If one is changed, only that one need to be compiled again and archived in a code version system. Splitting the class definition and its methods in 2 different files helps in that goal.

Anyway, both styles are allowed per the standard, and it has no impact on run time performance

Comment: It can have impact on runtime performance. If you define method inside class definition, they can be inlined and optimized much more easily.